# Views List Needs to be re-displayed to have a Full Listing

Tags: drupal-views

I have built a list of Participants, using Views, and defined some "exposed" filters (some of them based upon custom fields).

When I display this View, only a fiew participants are displayed, though all filters are set to "all".

I need to re-display (click the Display button) to get the full list (without changing anything).

Is this a bug, or did I miss something ? Is there a way to get around that ?

Comment: This sounds a lot like [CRM-20292](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20292). You may want to coordinate with John Kirk, who is investigating this issue.

Comment: are you setting the defaults for the exposed filters in each filter setting?

Comment: @ jackrabbithanna : Yes, I set default to "all", but when I re-edit the filter, it is set to "false" (in fact, I can't change it), but, however, when I display the View, it is set to "all" : very strange !

Comment: One thing that I notice : when I call the View, the URL is mysite.com/my_view ; but then, when I click "Display", the URL is changed with all the filters (set to their default values) : mysite.com/my_view?filter1=All&filter2=All&... (and then only, the View is complete). Why isn't the URL directly in the second form ?